# Why doesn't my connect middleware pass forward?

Tags: node.js, middleware, node.js-connect

I am using `"connect": "^3.3.5"`, I have `app.use '/', messageMiddleware.incoming, userMiddleware.process`

My `messageMiddleware` has:

```
exports.incoming = (req, res, next) ->
  fromNumber = req.body.From
  toNumber = req.body.To

  global.db.Message.create
    message: req.body.Body.trim()
    from: fromNumber
    to: toNumber
  .then (dbMessage) ->
    req.MessageId = dbMessage.id

    next()
  .catch (err) ->
    next err
```

My `userMiddleware` has

```
'use strict'

exports.process = (req, res, next) ->
  console.log 'processing'
  res.end()
```

However, it doesn't log `processing` or `end`. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Are you certain it's not hitting an error somewhere?

Comment: What is "global.db.Message.create"? Are you sure the promise is resolved? try to put a console.log in the then and in the catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `exports.incoming`, try `module.exports = {incoming: (req, res, next) ->...}`